# Calculate output power of sine and triangular wave

Tags: power, wave, sine

What is the mathematical expression to calculate the power dissipated by a load crossed by two separate electrical signals representing two specific mathematical functions knowing:

- Load resistance
- Frequency and period of the function
- The time when the function starts
- The time period in which calculate the power dissipation
- Starting voltage and peak of the function
- Assuming that voltage and current are in perfect phase

[image]

Specifically, I need to calculate the total power that crosses the load over time from 0 to T (the red part), of two mathematical functions: the sinusoidal one and the triangular one.

The image is for example only, I need a generic formula to apply to various voltages and times.

Comment: p(t) = i(t) * v(t).

Comment: To what is the *other* side of the load connected?  This sounds suspiciously like homework, but it's an under-defined problem - it's extremely unusual that you would have an *offset* sine wave appearing across a load, rather than a zero-centered one.  If the concept is unclear, start by reading up on the idea of RMS.  Generally though, integrate the instantaneous power through the resistive load as a function of time, then average over a period.

Comment: you'll need to determine v(t) and i(t) to calculate p(t) for a start

Comment: @ChrisStratton This is not homework, it is a basic calculation that I am trying to implement in a speech that I am arguing. About what happens when the slew of a sine wave is so low that it turns it into a triangular shape. And for this I am comparing the two powers dissipated over time, both by the sinusoid and by the triangular shape. However, I specified that the time in which I calculate it can be variable, consequently: I could also calculate a semi-sinusoid. However, the load is connected to ground

Comment: This is basic math you can do yourself, but beware that you are using these waveforms with an unusual DC bias.